# Типы данных в QTableWidget

Tags: сниппет, qt, c++

Подскажите, как можно задать тип вводимых данных для ячеек QTableWidget? Если можно, пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

В каком плане тип? Не совсем понятно что именно необходимо. Включу экстрасенсорику:

```
widget = new QTableWidget(this);
button=new QPushButton("Button",this);
label = new QLabel("Label");
widget->setRowCount(1);
widget->setColumnCount(2);
widget->setCellWidget(0,0,button);
widget->setCellWidget(0,1,label);
```

То?

Comment: Нет, тип всмысле тип вводимых данных, а именно числовые данные, int например, что бы пользователь не мог вводить никаких символов, кроме 0-9

Comment: все, разобрался сам, вопрос снят

Comment: Закройте вопрос